Conditions that a sequence should satisfy to be an eventually monotone sequence
Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that:

$a_n\in[0,1]$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$
$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$
$a_{n+1} \leq a_n$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ (decreasing sequence)
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}$ (increasing sequence)

Prove or disprove that:
$$
b_n = na_n \mbox{ is eventually monotone}
$$
so that there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{b_n\}_{n\geq n_0}$ is a monotone sequence.
Context
Unfortunately I haven't an "analalytic form" for the sequence $a_n$... it can not be computed explicitely. Although I know that it converges to 1 and that it is bounded in $[0,1]$, and that the quotient between consecutive terms goes to $1$ (with an increasing behavior).
Idea
One idea to prove that $\{b_n\}$ is eventually monotone, is to prove that:
$$
\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \geq 1 \mbox{ or } \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \leq 1 \mbox{ $\forall n\geq n_0$}
$$
so that:
$$
\frac{(n+1)a_{n+1}}{na_n} \geq 1 \mbox{ or } \frac{(n+1)a_{n+1}}{na_n} \leq 1 \mbox{ $\forall n\geq n_0$}
$$
The main problem is that I don't know the rate of convergence of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ to $1$, I only know that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is monotone increasing.

Just a disclaimer: I haven't downvoted  to give a chance to improve the question, but as a longer term user: You will probably already know by now that you have to show your efforts/ give context.

Sorry, I've just returned home.. I'll write it better. Thank you for pointing it out.

The statement is false, $b_n$ can be non monotone. I give you a counterexample.
Consider the sequence $a_n$ recursively defined as
$$ a_0 = 1,$$
$$a_{2m+1} = a_{2m}\cdot \frac{12m^2+12m+1}{12m^2+18m+6}, \quad\text{for $m \geq 0$},$$
and
$$ a_{2m}=a_{2m-1}\cdot\frac{12m^2-12m+2}{12m^2-6m}, \quad\text{for $m \geq 1$}.$$
We firstly prove that $\{a_n\}$ satisifes the hypothesis, and then that $b_n$ is not monotone. First define
$$ \alpha_m = \frac{12m^2+12m+1}{12m^2+18m+6}$$
and
$$ \beta_m = \frac{12m^2-12m+2}{12m^2-6m},$$
so that $a_{2m+1} = \alpha_m \cdot a_{2m}$ and $a_{2m} = \beta_m \cdot a_{2m-1}$. You can easily check that $0 < \alpha_m< 1$ for any $m \geq 0$, and $0 < \beta_m< 1$ for any $m \geq 1$, so you have (1) for free. To prove that (2) is satisifed by $\{a_n\}$, notice that for $m > 1$
$$ a_{2m} \leq \beta_1 \dots \beta_m \qquad \text{and}\qquad a_{2m+1} \leq \alpha_0 \dots \alpha_m.$$
Hence it's sufficient to prove that the two products go to zero as $m \rightarrow \infty$. We can write
$$ \alpha_k = 1 - \frac{6k + 5}{12k^2 + 18k + 6}$$
and
$$ \beta_k = 1 -  \frac{6k - 2}{12k^2 -6k}.$$
By this, it's then sufficient to prove that
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{6k + 5}{12k^2 + 18k + 6} $$
and
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{6k - 2}{12k^2 -6k} $$
both diverge, which is seen to be true by standard arguments using the harmonic series. We can conclude that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ as the sequence is dominated by a sequence going to zero. Hence (2) holds.
Condition (3) is much easier, since $\frac{a_{2m+1}}{a_{2m}} = \alpha_m$, $\frac{a_{2m}}{a_{2m-1}} = \beta_m$, and $\alpha_m, \beta_m \rightarrow 1$.
Condition (4) holds again because $\alpha_m, \beta_m < 1$.
Condition (5) is
$$ \alpha_m \geq \beta_m \qquad \text{and}\qquad \beta_m \geq \alpha_{m-1}.$$
The first inequality is
$$ \frac{12m^2+12m+1}{12m^2+18m+6} \geq  \frac{12m^2-12m+2}{12m^2-6m}, $$
while the second is
$$ \frac{12m^2-12m+2}{12m^2-6m} \geq  \frac{12(m-1)^2+12(m-1)+1}{12(m-1)^2+18(m-1)+6}.  $$
You can check that they both hold for $m \geq 1$ by hand (or choose your favorite solver if you are as lazy as me).
So we have a "right" sequence. Moreover, we have
$$ \frac{b_{2m+1}}{b_{2m}} = \frac{2m+1}{2m}\alpha_m = \frac{(2m+1)(12m^2+12m+1)}{2m(12m^2+18m+6)} > 1$$
and
$$ \frac{b_{2m}}{b_{2m - 1}} = \frac{2m}{2m-1}\beta_m = \frac{2m(12m^2-12m+2)}{(2m-1)(12m^2-6m)} < 1$$
again using our never-loved-enough solver.
I hope I did't make any mistake (WARNING: HIGH POSSIBILITY, PLEASE CHECK IT).
However, you might wonder how did I come to such a sequence. The trick is splitting it into two sequences depending on $n$ being even or odd, assuming $a_{2m+1} = \alpha_m a_{2m}$ and $a_{2m} = \beta_m a_{2m-1}$ for some $\alpha_m$ and $\beta_m$ and then carefully write all your conditions in this way.

I think you are correct! Thank you for this answer, I will recheck it again when I'll come home!
